# temp files in error with 7zip in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, 7zip

I am currently strugling on a simple powershell script to archive files.

I have thousand of old file in a folder and i want to archive them depending on the month/year of their creation date in archives named "YYYYMM".

I use the code below

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -filter $filter  |
Where-Object {(($_.CreationTime) -le $dateCriteria) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|
ForEach {
    $archive = "{0:yyyy}{0:MM}.7z" -f $_.CreationTime
    $archivePath= Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath $archive
    & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -t7z -m0=lzma2 -sdel $archivePath$_.FullName  |Out-Null
}
```

The logic seems fine as it creates  files like
201809.7z
201810.7z
...
In my destination folder.

The problem is i see errors in the console:

```
System ERROR:
The file exists
```

or

```
System ERROR:
Access denied
```

or

```
System ERROR:
The file exists
ERROR: ********\202011.7z
Can not open the file as archive
```

As a result, in my destination folder, in addition to the expected archive files i have file like "201810.7z.tmp1"

I changes the working directory to isolate those files by adding  `-w"{WORK_PATH}"`
to the command line.

I also added `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1`
as it looked like concurrent access even if my script is mono threaded (maybe 7zip doesn't end properly) but it didn't work.

With `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500`it seems to work but for obvious reasons i dont want to use that. What would the proper way to do that be ?

*****EDIT 1*****
Following MisterSmith's answer i changed my code for

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $emplacementSource -filter $filtreNomFichiers  |
Where-Object {(($_.CreationTime) -le $dernierJour) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}|
ForEach {
    $archive = "{0:yyyy}{0:MM}.7z" -f $_.CreationTime
    $cheminArchive= Join-Path -Path $dossierCible -ChildPath $archive
    [Array]$arguments = "a" ,"-w$workDir", "-mx9" ,"-t7z" ,"-m0=lzma2" ,"-sdel" ,$cheminArchive, $_.FullName    
    
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = $sevenZip
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.CreateNoWindow= $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = "$arguments"
    
    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $process.Start() 
    
    $output = $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    
    $process.WaitForExit()
                        
    if(0 -ne $process.ExitCode){                                                
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Erreur: $output"  | Out-file $fichierLogs -append
    }
}
```

I still have `File exists` errors and `.tmpX` archives in my temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `&` use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) and pass the `-wait` switch or use `-PassThru` switch and the returned `System.Diagnostics.Process` to check if the process has finished yourself. Either will get the same result as your `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500` test, but it will only wait for the time taken by 7z.exe to complete its execution.

---

Side note - you can append multiple files at once. That would probably work out quicker overall than adding each file separately.

Comment: In theory your answer is perfectly what i was looking for. But i still have "File exists" errors.